# Websphere MQ - Multi-Instance Manager Active/Standby Startup on Boot

Tags: ibm-mq

We have new MQ Managers (version 9) Multi-Instance setup which are running on Windows Servers 2016.

When we start the MQ Managers using `strmqm -x` we can see that on one side the managers are active and on the other they are on standby as would be expected which is great.

We then reboot the server on one side and we can see that the STANDBY instances on the other side become ACTIVE as would be expected which is also great.

After the reboot however, the managers on the rebooted server do not seem to startup on standby mode (I am guessing this is because they are not being started with the `-x` option?). Is it possible to have managers start automatically on server bootup with `-x` option?

Answer (score 0):

strmqm -x should start the qmgr in standby mode, assuming there is already an active instance.  So the answer here is to ensure that you add the -x switch.

Comment: Again his question is about how to get the Windows servers that starts queue managers up on boot up to do the equivalent to `-x`, I didn't answer this question because I don't know the answer and do not have much experience on Windows.

Comment: AS @JoshMc mentioned, we do start the mgrs with `-x` switch (but this is currently being done manually). We are wondering if it is possible to have them started with `-x` switch at Windows boot time (i.e. when MQ service startsup, it starts the Managers with '-x' switch set).

Comment: OK got it.  Sorry, but I don't know the answer, then.  Should I delete this answer?  (I'm a newbie on S.O.)